# onCardBoardTrigger() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cardboard

i'm developing a Android cardboard app. I've developed correctly the renderer (using Rajawali libraries ) and the view. 
I bumped into this simple error : the magnetic trigger doesn't work!

Here's the code for the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends CardboardActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    MyRenderer renderer;
    Vibrator vib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        vib = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        RajawaliCardboardView view = new RajawaliCardboardView(this);
        setContentView(view);
        setCardboardView(view);

        renderer = new MyRenderer(this);
        view.setRenderer(renderer);
        view.setSurfaceRenderer(renderer);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCardboardTrigger() {
        super.onCardboardTrigger();
        Log.d(TAG,"TRIGGER CARDBOARD \n");
        vib.vibrate(1000);
    }
}
```

It's a simple override of the onCardboardTrigger(), which should display me a debug log message and vibrate.

Instead in the logcat, when I try to pull the trigger here's what it displays :

```
09-01 13:00:24.290 15352-15352/com.eje_c.rajawalicardboard D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
    09-01 13:00:24.470 15352-15352/com.eje_c.rajawalicardboard D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

Comment: Rajawali library is still using googlevr version 0.6.0, by now the CardboardActivity is refactored in GvrActivity, is it possible it's that the problem?

Comment: What sdk version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Library didn't support lateste gvr sdk, that happens to have some issues with the trigger.
I've refactored some code in order to get Gvr v1.0.0 working with that library.